# High shuffle write and high execution time

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, amazon-emr, shuffle

I'm using EMR and I'm developing a collaborative-filtering approach with ALS. I have three doubt:

1. In order to see the execution time in Spark UI, I do several experiments. I've noticed that with one master and 4 workers the execution time is less than the EMR cluster with one master and six workers. Anyone know why?
2. The other thing is shuffle write. With one master and six workers, I have 3,2GB. Is it too high, isn't it? In the code I use RDD, groupbykey and I do two join. How can I minimize it?
3. With one master and six workers, the execution time is 7,5 min. Considering I'm using the Movielens Dataset, with Machine Learning approach I can't understand if this execution time is too high or it's quite good.

I attach a picture with the result form the Spark UI.
[image]
Thank you in advance

Comment: have you noticed that executor (4) was processing much more data than the others?

Comment: yes, I've noticed. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Share the code maybe your data is skewed or shuffling is not proper